# Good practice to call a static function inside class or struct

Tags: c++, function, static

I wonder what is the better practice to call a static function(and variables) inside a class or struct between A and B.

```
A: ClassName::functionName();

B: functionName();
```

Here's my simple example code:

In header file,

```
typedef struct _mystruct
{
    static void myfunction();
} t_mystruct;
```

And in CPP file,

```
void t_mystruct::myfunction()
{
   //do something
}
```

Now, in the same CPP file, what is the better practice to call this static function between A and B?

```
A: t_mystruct::myfunction();

B: myfunction();
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need that typedef wrapper. That's a C leftover. `struct t_mystruct { /* whatever */ }` is all you need in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling straight `myfunction();` is only feasible if you are inside `t_mystruct`'s implementation. In which case you can do according to your preferred coding style:

```
// .h
struct t_mystruct // You can declare it directly that way
{
    static void myfunction();
    void myOtherFunction();
};

// .cpp
void t_mystruct::myOtherFunction()
{
   myfunction(); // That's fine!
   t_mystruct::myfunction(); // That's fine too!
}
```

Otherwise, you have to explicitely use its fully qualified name:

```
void anywhereElse()
{
   t_mystruct::myfunction(); // Mandatory
   myfunction(); // Does not compile
}
```

This is true for your whole codebase, not only for the considered .cpp file.